# jaxb xmlElement namespace not working

Tags: namespaces, jaxb

I'm having trouble adding namespace to property for some time now. My requirement is to create xml which will have namespace uri on child element rather than root. I'm using jaxb with eclipselink moxy, jdk7.

```
<document>
<Date> date </Date>
</Type>type </Type>
<customFields xmlns:pns="http://abc.com/test.xsd">
  <id>..</id>
  <contact>..</contact>
</customFields>
</document>

Classes are:

@XmlRootElement(name = "document")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(propOrder = {"type","date", "customFields"})
public class AssetBean {

@XmlElement(name="Type")
private String type;
@XmlElement(name="Date")


@XmlElement(name = "CustomFields",namespace = "http://api.source.com/xsds/path/to/partner.xsd")    
private CustomBean customFields = new CustomBean();

//getters/setters here
```

}

```
public class CustomBean {

 private String id;
 private String contact;
 //getter/setter
}
package-info.java
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema (        
 xmlns = { 
 @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix="pns",
           namespaceURI="http://api.source.com/xsds/path/to/partner.xsd")
 },
elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.UNQUALIFIED
)
package com.abc.xyz
```

I followed this article for help but cant get what I'm trying
http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Domain Model (Root)**

In the domain object below I'll assign a namespace to one of the elements using the `@XmlElement` annotation.

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

    String foo;

    @XmlElement(namespace="http://www.example.com")
    String bar;

}
```

**Demo Code**

In the demo code below we will create an instance of the domain object and marshal it to XML.

```java
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        Root root = new Root();
        root.foo = "FOO";
        root.bar = "BAR";

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is the output of running the demo code.  The element that we assigned the namespace to with the `@XmlElement` annotation is properly namespace qualified, but the namespace declaration appears on the root element.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:ns0="http://www.example.com">
   <foo>FOO</foo>
   <ns0:bar>BAR</ns0:bar>
</root>
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

Comment: thanks for quick reply. I tried all examples you've given on your blog. Unfortunately, I need the xmlns to be on child node than the root node. Currently I'm setting xmls on package level as I also have requirement for customized namespace prefix. is there any other way/tweak to put namespace on child node and not on the root?

Comment: @user2361862 - Which part of your XML document is qualified by that namespace?  In your question nothing is.

Comment: I agree but client's document has that requirement. May be I should verify that xml again.. thanks for you help. Your blog has helped me to great extend as this is the first time I'm using jaxb and moxy.